# Aws Lambda s3 trigger stops working after I invoke it by other lambda using boto3 and arn

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, invoke

I have an aws lambda function which is being triggered when I upload a html in s3 bucket and it works fine.
Then I updated the code a little bit so I can invoke it by another lambda using boto3's client.invoke (pyhton3) as well but as soon as I invoked it by another lambda using boto3 it stops working for s3. (It still works fine when I invoke it with boto3).

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    api_flag = False
    if 'api_call' in event and event['api_call'] is True:
        api_flag = True
        data = event
    else:
        #code if its triggered by s3. 
        print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
        print("Received context: ", context)
    if api_flag is True:
        return{success:200}
```

I expected it to be triggered by both methods.

Comment: double-check that you did not change the lambda name and that s3 has still permissions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html, you should also see the invocation in cloudtrail.

Comment: Does it still show the S3 Trigger in the Lambda management console when viewing the function?

Comment: Yes it still shows the S3 Trigger in the Lambda management console